# How to handle sample/example links with possible Not Safe For Work content?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, offensive, external-links

This question came up a little more than 30 minutes ago, and contains a link to an example of what the poster is asking about.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24660027/change-background-inside-a-button-when-selected?noredirect=1#comment38229239_24660027

I've got a bit of downtime at work, so I click on it to see what they're referring to, and it's an image gallery with some questionable content that may not be suitable for work. It's not outright pornographic material, but a few images of scantily clad women graced my screen, and had the wrong person been walking by it could have been a bad day at work for me.

My question is how to handle these items? Flag them? Edit the post to clearly let others know that the link may contain content that's not suitable for work?

I commented on the post and saved someone from clicking it accidentally, but it's possible someone could click it without reading my comment first.

Comment: The comment posted below the question seems sufficient.  How bad are these images anyway?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I guess? As I stated, it's possible someone could click the link before seeing my comment, thus negating its effectiveness.

Comment: Well, hell.  I clicked on it anyway, expecting to get a goatse or something, and got [this](http://csstemplateheaven.com/demo/photobiz/images/pin3.jpg).  Unless you're living in Afghanistan under Taliban rule, what's the big deal?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: "a few images of scantily clad women" is goatse? That's not the same description I heard before...

Comment: Because someone else may find that wholly inappropriate while at work? I wouldn't think much of it, but someone else walking by may not think the same and thus ruin my day as a result.

Comment: I think the comment is more than sufficient.

Comment: Generally scenarios like this tend to be poorly asked - if someone can't be bothered to create an SSCCE then I'd act on that rather than morals first. (Compared to some this instance is pretty inoffensive)

Comment: @Flexo: This particular question is just fine though. Perhaps it could even hold its own without the example link - but then someone will complain about no fiddle.

Comment: What if it was a catalogue of women's tights, or a bodybuilding website, or just some guys picture gallery with beach snaps of his girlfriend? IMO if a couple of small, completely tasteful pictures of a female bodybuilder is NSFW for you then you probably shouldn't be clicking through to links when you have no idea what is on the other side, or at least you should wait until there is no one standing behind you. Comment is plenty enough warning

Comment: What is SSCCE? 15 characters.

Comment: @Mr.Manager: http://sscce.org/.  It's the first match in a Google Search for SSCCE.

Comment: I didn't google it first.  Only because that usually ends with a list of possibilities for an acronym.

Comment: I had a [similar situation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978588/gifs-opened-with-python-have-ruined-frames) a while back, but the linked images in that case were more clearly NSFW and the OP was much more rude/abrasive about it - eventually mods removed the question in that case.

Comment: It's Stack Overflow: just edit OP to include the warning? There are mechanisms in place for people to refuse such suggested edits if they are inappropriate, no? Seems reasonable in this case. Not porn, but corner of eye glance could raise an eyebrow in a bad way at work. Plus, that is just one example, this question is more general. E.g., what if someone DID post to clearly nsfw material that was required for the question?