# A question links to a very NSFW site

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, offensive, external-links

This is similar to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263143/how-to-handle-sample-example-links-with-possible-not-safe-for-work-content) question, but I just came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25045915/3204827) question and it links to a site that is definitely not safe for work (it's an escort site with nude women on the ads).

On the other meta thread, the website in question had "a few images of scantily clad women" and not any actual pornographic material, so the comment "Just a heads up, some of the images in his link may be NSFW...." is enough, but in this case I'm not too sure (I did add that comment and edited it into the post).

Is the warning and comment enough or should it be closed/link removed?

Comment: If the link isn't essential to the question, then edit it out. You could also flag as offensive if you suspect the OP is trolling.

Comment: Questions need to be self-containing. So the link is irrelevant and should be removed.

Comment: The thing is: that was more spam than anything else. But the OP didn`t hide the fact that it was a NSFW site (the title is quite explicit by itself). It would be much worse if the user said: I looked into [the docs](http://somerandompornosite.com) and you got a surprise. PS: I don't know if the link in this comment is valid, but I don't want to check it either.

Comment: "I looked into [the docs](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rickrolling) and you got a surprise" - Anyone already tried a rickroll on SO?

Comment: Time to look at the revision history...

Comment: @juergend, it's not always practical to require questions to be self contained. If a big amount of code is relevant it might be better to post in on pastebin or similar, and quote only most important parts. Links to test sites that can exhibit and/or reproduce the problem are also very helpful while answering, because the answerer can try it out on the site linked in the question. There is a reason why links are allowed. Technically it's very easy (for SO team) to not allow them in questions.

Comment: @zespri I'm sorry, but at the end of the day, *yes*, **questions do need to be self-contained**. If you have to use a 3rd-party external service to host your boat-load of code, then you haven't narrowed down your problem enough to make an appropriate question for [main]. If that 3rd-party service ever goes offline, your question has now become **absolutely useless** to future readers.

Comment: @juergend: Now that's just silly.  "I'm trying to implement Karger's minimum cut algorithm described in such-and-such paper" doesn't need to repeat the contents of the paper.  Why should links be different?

Comment: @tmyklebu: Because links can break and then the question is useless it the link contained vital information. And we want posts being preserved for future visitors

Comment: @juergend: You do not seem to have thought this through.  (Or you're not accurately expressing your opinion.)  How does one ask a question about a software package?  One links to it.  "Why is GLPK 4.42 blowing up when I tell it to do this reasonable thing?" benefits from a link to GLPK, but it's made useless if the poster is forced to reduce GLPK and his code to a SSCCE.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Links for additional info are fine, but not if they contain info that is essential to the question. And if you think the SSCCE close reason should be removed then you are welcome to start a meta discussion about it.

Comment: Damnit.  Barcelona only.